# I cant understand how I wrote this code please, guide

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, syntax

This is my full page code, but notice the error in writing which line is causing the error.

> **You have an error in your SQL syntax;** check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id']; ?>'' at line 131)

When I write this `$getpost = $db->select($query_edit);` code, this type of error appears on my admin page, I do not understand what to do, I have tried many things, but error is not resolved!

```
<?php
$query_edit = "SELECT * FROM tbl_post WHERE id='$editpost' ";
$getpost = $db->select($query_edit);// This is the line that caused this error to be written
```

My admin panel image:

[image]

Comment: As the error message states, your SQL is invalid. Correct it and it should work. Also don't put variables in SQL, use parameters. You also are not likely to be using `mysql` and `sql-server` those are 2 different database systems

Comment: The error in your screen shot is different than the error you typed in the question. Based on your screen shot it appears that the `select` method of your `$db` object is adding more SQL code to your query before executing it against the database. The error is probably caused by that additional code.

Comment: Probably, You configured ID column with number type and set query compare with string. Let try replace id='$editpost' with id= $editpost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using quotes improperly.
You can but shouldn't do this.... 
`$query_edit = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_post WHERE id="' . $editpost . '"';`

You leave yourself open to SQL injection. Look up PDO prepared statements.